# Rails – how to import files from localhost to heroku db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, thor

I have 2 models – Document and Attachment. I'm trying to import a lot of files to my heroku db. I have also thor task for it. It works fine when I run this task with my local db, but when I try to run it in stage env, I have an error at "document.save" action:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=stage thor import:documents '/path/to/files/'

/../gems/fog-1.10.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:23:in `digest': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
```

Also, when I upload file via form on heroku app, everything works great. So what's the problem?

Here are models:

Attachment:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  IMAGE_TYPES = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']
  DOC_TYPES = ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'pages', 'txt']

  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  attr_accessible :attachment_file, :attachment_file_cache, :attachment_type

  mount_uploader :attachment_file, AttachmentUploader

  validates :attachment_file, presence: true

  ...

 end
```

Document:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :visible, :attachment_attributes
  has_one :attachment, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Attachment', conditions: { attachment_type: 'document' }
  ...
end
```

Thor task:

```
class Import < Gearup::TasksBase
  desc "documents <DOCUMENTS_FOLDER>", 'Upload documents'
  def documents(dir_path)
    dir_path += "#{dir_path.last == '/' ? '*' : '/*'}"
    print_color_message('! Directory is empty !', 'red') if Dir[dir_path].empty?
    Dir[dir_path].each do |file_path|
      document = Document.new(title: 'document_title')
      document.build_attachment(attachment_type: 'document', attachment_file: File.open(file_path))

      if document.save  ### HERE IS A PROBLEM ###
        print_color_message("-= document \"#{document.title}\" successfully created =-", 'green')
      else
        print_color_message("! document not saved !", 'red')
        print_color_message(document.errors.messages.inspect, 'red')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I didn't forget to edit my database.yml with

```
heroku pg:credentials HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL
```

database.yml

```
...

stage:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <database_name>
  host: <host_name>
  sslmode: <sslmode>
  port: <port>
  pool: <pool>
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to upload directly to heroku because I don't believe heroku allows you to store files locally.

Comment: I believe kenjione is trying to upload files to amazon-s3 storage, using carrierwave + fog, from local machine, running thor task with RAILS_ENV=stage (which allows to connect to remote db).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you forgot to setup s3 credentials in your config.
Heroku takes it from ENV.